# T-SQL - Flagging Common Values in One Column Based on ID and updating the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Problem Statement:
There are Two Columns, VariableName and ID. I want to map variables in the same column with a two-character alpha code such as 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'.... up to 'zz' in T-SQL.

To Illustrate,

**Input Data:**

```
VariableName      ID      MapFlag        isMapped
var_1             1         NULL           FALSE
var_2             1         NULL           FALSE
var_3             1         NULL           FALSE
var_4             1         NULL           FALSE
var_5             1         NULL           FALSE
var_1             2         NULL           FALSE
var_2             2         NULL           FALSE
var_3             2         NULL           FALSE
var_10            2         NULL           FALSE
var_11            2         NULL           FALSE
var_1             3         NULL           FALSE
var_10            3         NULL           FALSE
var_3             3         NULL           FALSE
var_7             3         NULL           FALSE
var_1             4         NULL           FALSE
var_2             4         NULL           FALSE
var_4             4         NULL           FALSE
```

**Desired Output**

```
VariableName      ID      MapFlag        isMapped
var_1             1          aa           TRUE
var_2             1          ab           TRUE
var_3             1          ac           TRUE
var_4             1          ad           TRUE
var_5             1          NULL         FALSE
var_1             2          aa           TRUE
var_2             2          ab           TRUE
var_3             2          ac           TRUE
var_10            2          ae           TRUE
var_11            2          NULL         FALSE
var_1             3          aa           TRUE
var_10            3          ae           TRUE 
var_3             3          ac           TRUE
var_7             3          NULL         FALSE
var_1             4          aa           TRUE
var_2             4          ab           TRUE 
var_4             4          ad           TRUE
```

As you can see above,

- "var_1" , is present in ids 1, 2, 3, 4 and is tagged as 'aa'
- "var_2" , is present in ids 1, 2 and 4 and is tagged as 'ab'
- "var_3" , is present in ids 1, 2 and 3 and is tagged as 'ac'
- "var_4" , is present in ids 1, and 4 and is tagged as 'ad'
- "var_5" , is present in id 1 **BUT IS NOT PRESENT IN THE REST OF THE
  IDs**, so hence NULL
- "var_7" , is present in id 3 **BUT IS NOT PRESENT IN THE REST OF THE
  IDs**, so hence NULL
- "var_10" , is present in ids 2 and 3 and is tagged as 'ae'
- "var_11" , is present in id 2 **BUT IS NOT PRESENT IN THE REST OF THE
  IDs**, so hence NULL

To summarize: Essentially, I want to create a mapping flag with the pattern above 'aa', 'ab', 'ac'
among different IDs. If the mapFlag is NOT NULL, then isMapped TRUE else FALSE

Lastly, I want to write an "Update" stored procedure to convert the input "MapFlag" column with the Input Data and then update the table with the Output data

Comment: Your var names sorted order is `var_1, var_10, var_11, var_2 ..` Why `ab` should be assigned to `var_2` ?

Comment: In this particular problem, the order does not matter. var_2 could be tagged as 'ac' or 'zz'. What's important is that if var_2 is present in more than 1 IDs, then it should be tagged by a unique 2 letter character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query to get var marks.

```
select VariableName,  char(ASCII('a')+rn/(ASCII('z') - ASCII('a') +1)) + char(ASCII('a') -1 + rn%(ASCII('z') - ASCII('a') +1)) y
from (
    select  VariableName, row_number() over (order by VariableName) rn
    from mytable
    group by VariableName
    having count(distinct id) > 1
) t
```